# Potential memory leaks in reading binary files

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, binaryfiles, binary-data

I would like to ask if this part of the code might suffer from memory leaks (I'm quite sure it does, but how severely?).

The "input" variable is a pointer to double, i.e. double* input. The reason I didn't use float (more compatible in this case) is because I wanted to maintain compatibility with other parts of the code.

```
else if (filetype == "BinaryFile")
{
    char* memblock;
    std::ifstream file(filename1, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::cout << "Size=" << size << " [in bytes]"
              << "\n";
    std::cout << "There are overall " << grid_points << "^3 = " << std::setprecision(10) << pow(grid_points, 3) << " values of the field1, written as float type.\n";
    memblock = new char[size];
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    file.read(memblock, size);
    file.close();
    float* values = (float*)memblock; //reinterpret as float, because the file was saved as float
    for (int i = 0; i < grid_points * grid_points * grid_points; i++) {
        input1[i] = (double)values[i]; //cast to double, since input1 is an array of doubles
    }
    file.close();
    delete[] memblock;
}
```

The files that I need to work on are quite big, coming from cosmological simulations; for example one file is 4GB and the other could be 20 GB. I'm using the supercomputer infrastructure for that reason.

This kind of reading works for files that have 512^3 float values (e.x. density evaluated on points in a cube of side 512) but memory leaks happen for a file with 1024^3 entries.

I had thought I should delete[] the "values" array, but when I do that, I get even worse memory leaks, crashing my program even in the case where previously all was calculated correctly (512^3).

How could I improve on this code? I would have used the std::vector container but I had to use the FFTW library.

EDIT:

Following the suggestions in the comments, I have rewritten the reading part of the code as:

```
std::ifstream file(filename1,std::ios::binary);
std::vector<float> buf(pow(grid_points,3));
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), buf.size()*sizeof(float)); 
std::copy_n(buf.begin(),pow(grid_points,3),input1);
```

Where I explicitly make use of the knowledge of how many elements there will be in the input1 array. No memory leaks occur now.

Comment: If your files are that large, do you really need to allocate thrice as much memory just to read it once in `memblock` and then copy it to a second time to `input1` (twice as large as `memblock`)?

Comment: I don't really know how to do it in one step. I guess I cannot simply cast memblock to double, because that would read the memblock incorrectly

Comment: *I would have used the std::vector container but I had to use the FFTW library.* -- None of the code you posted would have prevented you from using `std::vector`.  For example, instead of :`memblock = new char[size];` you could have used `std::vector<char> memblock(size);` and save yourself the memory leak.

Comment: Also, isn't your calculation of floats backwards?  Take a small file -- if the size in bytes is 40, and `sizeof(float)` is 8, then there are 5 floats, not `grid_points * grid_points * grid_points` floats.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have managed to employ more C++ techniques, but I still use probably less-than-optimal way of converting into double.